# How to add checklistbox items into tablelayoutpanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel, checklistbox

How to add checklistbox values into tablelayout in window from c# here is my code

```
cbl.Items.Add(dt.Rows[r]["Option1"].ToString());
cbl.Items.Add(dt.Rows[r]["Option2"].ToString());
```

Above two items I want to add them in tablelayoutpanel how to do it. I am guessing to be as

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cbl.Items[0].ToString());
```

Comment: You are adding a String (.ToString()) to your panel instead of a control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
CheckedListBox cbl = new CheckedListBox();
cbl.Items.Add("Item 1");
cbl.Items.Add("Item 2");
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cbl);
```

Hope this will help